# Dúvida com Mysqli e PHP OO

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
public function registerUser($link, $nome, $sobrenome, $apelido) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estudo_oo (id, nome, sobrenome, apelido) VALUES ('', '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$apelido') ";
    if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
}
```

E minha duvida é: Eu teria que passar SEMPRE as variáveis por parâmetro ali na função? Porque tipo, se eu tiver um formulário com vários campos por exemplo, eu teria realmente que passar todas variáveis ali?

Eu fiz uns testes e tentei salvar o form sem passar as variáveis por parâmetro, mas não tive sucesso, daí acabou me surgindo essa dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo mais diretamente a sua pergunta:

> Eu teria que passar SEMPRE as variáveis por parâmetro **ali na função**?

Em algum momento você tem que passar os argumentos, seja definindo propriedades da classe, ou como argumentos do método. Qual das duas formas (ou ambas) você vai usar depende apenas das suas decisões para o projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Na orientação a objetos temos as propriedades da classe, que nada mais são que variáveis dentro do escopo da classe.

O `mysqli` permite tanto o método procedural (que é o que você está usando) como método orientado à objeto.

Não vou entrar em detalhes mais aprofundados, mas segue um exemplo simples de como utilizar as propriedades:

```
<?php

class Usuario {

    // A propriedade com uma conexão
    protected $dbConnection;

    // Método construtor para passagem do parâmetro (nesse caso sua conexão com banco)
    public function __construct(mysqli $dbConnection)
    {
        // Injeta a conexão criada na classe
        $this-> dbConnection = $dbConnection;
    }

    public function registerUser($nome, $sobrenome, $apelido) 
    {
        // Recomendo o uso de prepared statments para inserir os parâmetros
        $sql = "INSERT INTO estudo_oo (id, nome, sobrenome, apelido) VALUES ('', '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$apelido') ";

        // Procure usar Exceptions para tratamento de erros
        try {
            $this->query($sql);
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            return $e->message;
        }

        return true;

    }
}

// Como usar:

$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass');

$usuario = new Usuario($link);
$usuario->registerUser('João', 'Lucas', 'Jão');
```

Essas foram só algumas dicas de como implementar. Outras sugestões são [usar PDO ou invés de MySqli](http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) e ler um pouco mais do [básico no desenvolvimento em PHP moderno](http://br.phptherightway.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir valores padrão para os parâmetros que não pretende passar sempre:

```
public function registerUser($link, $nome, $sobrenome=null, $apelido=null) {

}
```

---

Nota: como você está usando mysqli, recomendo fortemente utilizar [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) em vez de concatenar as variáveis diretamente na query.

Comment: Bateu uma dúvida: passar uma variável nula em um prepared statement irá inserir o valor null no banco ou uma `string` vazia?

Comment: Se você usar `bind_param` e passar `null`, o valor `NULL` será inserido.